# Airflow not picking up cleared tasks in complete dag

Tags: python, celery, airflow

I'm running Airflow in a Celery cluster and I'm having trouble getting cleared tasks to run after their dag is already marked as success.

Say I have a dag in the following state:

[image: Successful dag run]

I want to run everything up to dummy_task_2 again for some reason. I run *clear upstream* on the task and everything before it is cleared:

[image: dag run with cleared tasks]

In this state the scheduler will *not* schedule tasks 1 and 6 for execution, *unless* I also clear tasks 5 or 4:

[image]

basically it seems as if the scheduler simply does not care about tasks in a dag if all the 'final' tasks are already marked as success. If I clear *those*, then it goes back and picks up all the cleared tasks.

I've googled the hell out of this and it doesn't seem like intended behavior. I've checked the scheduler logs and there's nothing unusual, it simply reports *No tasks to send to the executor* until I clear one of the last tasks in the dag.

Is this a bug? Are there any logs I could check to see what's happening? I've even tried manually changing the state of the dag in the metadata database from 'success' to 'running' but the scheduler just reverts it to 'success' immediately.

Comment: What is the state of the DAG after clearing the upstream tasks?

Comment: "Success". Tried both via UI and CLI, double checked the metadata schema just to be sure.

Comment: Can you try setting the state of the DAG manually to "running"

Comment: I have tried it. Did not work.

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Sadly no. I managed to get it to work by basically deleting the affected dags and tasks in the metadata database and letting the scheduler recreate them.